# Treat a string of words like an array (C++)

Tags: c++

Im trying to create a text-based game, im working in a team of other guys and im having a problem creating an item list.

I pretty much want a list of items like an array of words and being able to replace an item with another item by simply pointing to the item like you would pick up an item on your travels in the game.

Is this possible? Every website ive looked at has went into detail about creating an expandanble list of string or memory allocation. All i want to do is have a list of values that I can call from For example I imagined It could work like so.

```
 item1 = "Lint, dust, sword,axe,gem,Gold key, silver key";
 item2 = "Lint, dust, sword,axe,gem,Gold key, silver key";

cout << "Show:" << item1[3] << " and " << item2[2]
<< "\n";

"Show: Sword and Axe"
```

instead the outcome is usually "t", as in the 3rd character.

Also the reason I have this idea of working is because Ive worked with Matlab in creating something similar using an array and it worked, maybe thats why I think this should work so simply.

Comment: does each item list always have 7 items, or do you need to grow or shrink it? Also FYI the reason you're printing the third character is that a string in C++ is just an array of characters, so when you treat it like an array then each element in the array is a character.

Comment: @alexanderbird No its just going to be the same 7 items, its a static list.
Thanks for the tip, I got confused on how C++ saw string as arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>

const std::string list[5] = {"str1","str2","str3","str4","str5"};
```

Comment: I added the const keyword because comments in the OP made it clear that the list will be static

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `std::array`:

```
//Declare list of words
std::array<std::string, numwords> words1 = { "Lint", "Dust", "Sword", "Axe", "Gem", "Gold Key", "Silver key" };
```

Then you can access the words like you did:

```
words1[3]; //"Axe"
words1[2]; //"Sword"
```

Note that in C++ indices start from 0, not 1, so index 3 is actually the fourth element in the array.

Comment: To meet the spirit of what the OP requested you might add a "" as the first element of the array to convert it to 1's based indexing:

std::array<std::string, numwords> words1 = { "","Lint", "Dust", "Sword", "Axe", "Gem", "Gold Key", "Silver key" };

Comment: @Hucker I don't think he explicitly mentioned this, but nonetheless, this could cause problems with other developers who don't know that he counts from 1 and not from 0, so it should be avoided at best.